# Could anyone please help me identify who this is meant to be?

Tags: identification, asia, south-east-asia, central-asia, sculpture

I recently purchased this bust at an estate sale. It was advertised as an Egyptian goddess, but I don't think that is accurate at all. It looks to be more Asian in design. Any ideas who it is meant to represent? Maybe Guan Yin? (I don't have any illusions that this is a valuable artifact, by the way.  Pretty sure it's contemporary.)

[image: Side view of sculpture head and headdress]

[image: Front view of sculpture head and headdress]

Comment: What's material is it made of?

Comment: Just plaster.  Nothing fancy

Comment: [Guanyin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guanyin#:~:text=Usually%20contains%20an%20image%20of%20Buddha%20Amitabha%2C%20her%20teacher.) would seem to be a good prospect.